# convert an uploaded pdf to image to display on canvas

Tags: javascript, angular

i am uploading a pdf file in my angular application. i need to convert it to a image file and then it should be displayed in the canvas element. I did try the following way but it does not display the pdf file as image. if i upload a image then it is displayed but i need the pdf to be converted to image and then display. any idea please

on file upload:

```
fileBrowseHandler($event: any) {
    this.fileUploaded = true;
    let file = $event.target.files[0];
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onload = () => {
      this.url = reader.result;
      this.imageCanvas = new fabric.Canvas('image-canvas', {
      hoverCursor: 'pointer',
      selection: false,
      selectionBorderColor: 'green',
      backgroundColor: null
    });
    this.imageCanvas.setBackgroundImage(this.url, this.imageCanvas.renderAll.bind(this.imageCanvas), {
      backgroundImageOpacity: 0.5,
      backgroundImageStretch: false
    });

    };
}
```

in HTML file:

```
 <canvas id="image-canvas" width="700" height="1020" style="border: 1px solid gray;">
 </canvas>
```